# Where can I find the Torchlight 2 save folder?

Tags: torchlight-2

I'm playing Torchlight 2 and want backup my save but I cannot locate the save folder. I tried looking in `%APPDATA%\runic games\`, but the folder is empty. Where can I find the save files?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming Windows 7 or Vista, the save folder should be located in:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\My Games\Runic Games\Torchlight 2\save\
```

For Windows XP it is located in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\My Documents\My Games\Runic Games\Torchlight 2\save\
```

Comment: now I get it, thanks a lot dude.. you save my gamefile :D

Comment: @amp Happy to help! If the answer was useful you should mark it as accepted too.

Comment: sorry for that, I'm new here. Hahah! xD