# How to restore a Torchlight 2 saved game?

Tags: torchlight-2

I wanted to reinstall Torchlight 2 because of a bug which was preventing the game from launching. I backed up the save folder from the 'My Documents' directory and uninstalled/re-installed the game. I found the original save folder still there, but just to be sure I pasted the one I copied earlier.

When I launched the game I don't see my saved games, it just asked me to start a new game. I loved this game a lot and I had made some decent progress, I don't want to start again or for the worst scenario quit it.

Is there anything I can do to get back my save?

Comment: Is it through steam?

Comment: Did you happen to find [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85566/where-can-i-find-the-torchlight-2-save-folder/85567#85567)?  It tells you where the save game is.  If that's the one you backed up, it seems to be pretty straightforward.

Comment: If you're running any mods the save doesn't go in the normal location.

Comment: No it's not through steam, I do know how to back the save game and I also tried pasting the save game folder in modsave, nothing's working, I still get only the option of 'New Game' when I launch it